# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

Tags: flutter

whenever I try to run my flutter project they show,

> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

[image]

I have tried all possible ways to solve this error. I have solved all issues related to issues, but still, I can not overcome from this error.
I have even reinstalled my android-studio and flutter.

Comment: What is ```flutter doctor``` giving you?

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
 Doctor found issues in 1 categories.

Comment: I have updated and reinstalled my SDK Manager..though I get this error every time @Di

Comment: Did you try to run it on a physical device?

Comment: yes but i got error

Comment: Are you using latest Android Studio version?

Comment: Did you solve it? If so, please share your solution, I am also getting the same error.